# undefined method `create_translation_table!'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, globalize3

I have a new rails engine and I want to use globalize3. I did this in my lib//engine.rb :

```
require 'globalize3'

module SimpleCms
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
  end
end
```

Now, I try to create a migration like this :

```
class CreatePages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :pages do |t|
      t.string :path
      t.timestamps
    end
    Page.create_translation_table! title: :string, body: :body
  end

  def down
    drop_table :pages
    Page.drop_translation_table!
  end
end
```

And I have this error :

```
undefined method `create_translation_table!' for #<Class:0x00000001d5ca18>
```

I think the file 'lib/globalize/active_record/migration.rb' is not loaded.

Any solution?

Answer (score 25):

You have to add

```
translates :attributename
```

to your Engine model file before you run the migration. (Replace :attributename with the attribute you want to have translated). That fixed it for me.

Comment: This helped me a lot! Finally got it working this was the missing piece.

Comment: Nice shot :) it fixed my issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SimpleCms::Page.create_translation_table! title: :string, body: :body
```

but the foreign key will become `simplecms_page_id`, I manually change it back to `page_id`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, `globilize` gem wasn't working correctly, because `traco` gem was also in Gemfile. Removing `traco` fixed the error. So I guess only using one of translation gems is allowed